# Writing typesafe code without boilerplate

Tags: scala, types, type-safety

I'm working on some system that uses external configuration and does some action depending upon the configuration provided. I have the following traits (methods omitted for simplicity):

```
  sealed trait Tr[T]
  case object Tr1 extends Tr[String]
  case object Tr2 extends Tr[Int]
  case object Tr3 extends Tr[Array[Byte]]

  sealed trait Trr[T]
  case object Trr1 extends Trr[String]
  case object Trr2 extends Trr[Int]
  case object Trr3 extends Trr[Array[Byte]]


  trait Trrr[T]
  case object Trrr1 extends Trrr[(String, Int)]
  case object Trrr2 extends Trrr[(Int, String)]
  case object Trrr3 extends Trrr[(Int, Int)]
  case object Trrr4 extends Trrr[(String, String)]
  case object Trrr5 extends Trrr[(String, Array[Byte])]
```

And the action:

```
  def doUsefulAction[T, F](t1: Tr[T], t2: Trr[F], t3: Trrr[(T, F)]) = {
    //...
  }
```

The problem is the method invokation depends on the configuration:

```
  def invokeWithConfig[T1, T2, T3](cfgTr1: String, cfgTr2: String, cfgTr3: String) = cfgTr1 match {
    case "1" =>
      cfgTr2 match {
        case "1" =>
          cfgTr3 match {
            case "4" => doUsefulAction(Tr1, Trr1, Trrr4)
            case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
          }
        case "2" =>
          cfgTr3 match {
            case "1" => doUsefulAction(Tr1, Trr2, Trrr1)
            case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
          }
        case "3" =>
          cfgTr3 match {
            case "5" => doUsefulAction(Tr1, Trr3, Trrr5)
            case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
          }
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
      }
    case "2" =>
      //same boilerplate as above
    case "3" =>
      //same boilerplate as above
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
  }
```

The thing is there is tons of boilerplate with pattern matching. And this is just 3 traits. In case of 10 it becomes unreadable.

Is there a way to handle such a configuration yet staying types and avoid `instanceOf`?

Maybe `macro` can be useful here?

Answer (score 1):

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Z2NGo9y/0

This is a possible solution but it's not optimal yet you could eliminate more boilerplate by introducing something like shapeless/magnolia/scalaz-deriving to derive the implementations for the `fromString` implementations.

But really `Validated` and `Applicative` are your friends here

EDIT: As requested the code here

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.Validated._
import cats.data.ValidatedNel
import cats.data.NonEmptyList

sealed trait Tr[T]
case object Tr1 extends Tr[String]
case object Tr2 extends Tr[Int]
case object Tr3 extends Tr[Array[Byte]]

object Tr{
  def fromString(s:String):ValidatedNel[Throwable, Tr[_]] = s match {
    case "1" => Tr1.validNel
    case "2" => Tr2.validNel
    case "3" => Tr3.validNel
    case _ => new RuntimeException(s"$s is not a valid Tr").invalidNel
  }
}

sealed trait Trr[T]
case object Trr1 extends Trr[String]
case object Trr2 extends Trr[Int]
case object Trr3 extends Trr[Array[Byte]]

object Trr{
  def fromString(s:String):ValidatedNel[Throwable, Trr[_]] = s match {
    case "1" => Trr1.validNel
    case "2" => Trr2.validNel
    case "3" => Trr3.validNel
    case _ => new RuntimeException(s"$s is not a valid Trr").invalidNel
  }
}


trait Trrr[T, T1]
case object Trrr1 extends Trrr[String, Int]
case object Trrr2 extends Trrr[Int, String]
case object Trrr3 extends Trrr[Int, Int]
case object Trrr4 extends Trrr[String, String]
case object Trrr5 extends Trrr[String, Array[Byte]]

object Trrr{
  def fromString(s:String):ValidatedNel[Throwable, Trrr[_, _]] = s match {
    case "1" => Trrr1.validNel
    case "2" => Trrr2.validNel
    case "3" => Trrr3.validNel
    case "4" => Trrr4.validNel
    case "5" => Trrr5.validNel
    case _ => new RuntimeException(s"$s is not a valid Trrr").invalidNel
  }
}

def doUseful[T1, T2](tr:Tr[T1], trr:Trr[T2], trrr:Trrr[T1,T2]):String = "called"


def dispatch(s1:String, s2:String, s3:String):Either[Throwable, String] = (
    Tr.fromString(s1),
    Trr.fromString(s2),
    Trrr.fromString(s3),
  )
  .tupled
  .leftMap( 
    errs => new RuntimeException(
      Foldable[NonEmptyList].intercalate(errs.map(_.getMessage),"\n")
      )
    )
  .toEither
  .flatMap {
    case (a@Tr1, b@Trr2, c@Trrr1) => Right(doUseful(a,b,c))
    case _ => Left(new RuntimeException("non mapped possibility"))
    //note the line below won't compile because there's no valid combination of T1, T2 to call doUseful
    //case (a@Tr1, b@Trr2, c@Trrr4) => doUseful(a,b,c)
  }

println(dispatch("1", "2", "1"))
println(dispatch("1", "2", "15"))
println(dispatch("1", "20", "15"))
```

Comment: Dominic, putting all the code to an outside resource is a bad practice at SO. Those links tend to become stale in time. Could you please copy the essence of the solution into your answer as well?

Comment: You can always describe the essence of the plan in words as well :). I wonder if this is what OP is after. It might be, because it does remove some boilerplate. But for me the really interesting part of the question is how to remove the explicit mapping stage but still preserve the filtering that is implied by the type constraint of the `doUsefulAction`. I mean the constraint that of all the `(Tr[A], Trr[B], Trrr[(C,D)])` the valid ones are only those where `A =:= C` and `B =:= D`. It looks like your code doesn't solve this problem at all. Am I right?

Comment: actually it should as scalac is able to refine `T1` and `T2` in the cases and if there's no instance of `Trrr[T1,T2]` you can't call `doUseful`. see the commented line. 

the more common pattern in scala would be to make `Trrr` instances implicit and call it "evidence" usecases for this would be e.g. modeling relations ships like numeric widening, castability or subtyping (see Liskov in scalaz/cats)

Comment: The problem is that you have to explicitly list all the allowed mappings in the last `flatMap` even despite the fact that potentially all the required information is already in the types. It is not like we change the order of the arguments, we always pass them in the same order. So my question (not sure if it is the OP's as well) is: can you write a code in such a way that you don't have to explicitly write all the allowed mappings?

Comment: Hmm. I can't really think of how you would do that off the top of my head. The problem I see is that you need a place in the code where the compiler is able to infer the types (the cases).

Comment: Dominic, as I said I'm not the OP but if I was asking such a question, this is the part I would be after because mapping string onto a sealed trait is kind of a trivial problem. This one is hard and is worth asking. Still it might be that your answer is what the OP wants.

Comment: I understand that and it is an intriguing problem. I'll give it a crack.
Maybe you could do something with Derivations over the complete combinations of `T1 <: Tr` and `T2 <: Trr` probably that calls `Right(doSomethingUsefu)l` for a valid combination and `Left(error)` for invalid combinations

Comment: @SergGr I gotta bolt but maybe something along those lines https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Z2NGo9y/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187134/discussion-between-serggr-and-dominic-egger).